# How to Change the IconSize for Actions in QMenu?

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu

I am trying to resize the Icons of QActions in the QMenu with the following code but it doesn't work.

```
QMenu *menu;
menu =new QMenu();
menu->setStyleSheet("QMenu::icon{height:20px;width:20px});"
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could provide a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can set style sheet to manage icon size like this:

```
QAction *action = new QAction("Exit", this);
action->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/resources/exit.png"));


QMenu *menu = new QMenu("File");
menu->addAction(action);
menu->setStyleSheet("QMenu {icon-size: 200px;} QMenu::item {background: transparent;}");

ui->menubar->addMenu(menu);
```

[image: screenshot]

But it will display in an Improper size, so it's better to use [QToolBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtoolbar.html).

In your cpp file type this:

```
ui->ToolBarName->setIconSize(QSize(50,50));
```

In Designer Click on your QToolbar and set iconSize.

[image]

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager Absolutely agree. Thought I misread the post when I saw this was the accepted answer. Flagged.

Comment: You're right my friend, I updated my answer and explained it more, thanks for your reply. @EdwardSeverinsen

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
QMenu *menu;
menu =new QMenu();

QToolButton *button=new QToolButton(menu);
button->setFixedSize(50,50);
QWidgetAction *action=new QWidgetAction(this);
action->setDefaultWidget(button);
menu->addAction(action);
```

Comment: maybe you should accept your own answer if it solved it for you

Comment: I don't see any icon and text in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled across this after all these years. I remember I had this problem once and now again. This time I actually managed to solve it somewhat. It IS kinda weird tho and should receive some love at least documentation-wise.

The key is: You need to style `QMenu` AND `QMenu::item` If you just set the icon size via:

```
QMenu {icon-size: 40px;}
```

it will remain **ignored** until you also set something like

```
QMenu::item {background: transparent;}
```

Unfortunately this resets the menu stylesheet and you need to do something about the `hover` state to make it usable. But well.
Seems this works for me.

([also posted this on the qt forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/63483/qmenu-icon-size/6))

Comment: icon-size is not applicable for QMenu. Please check the documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-reference.html